# JavaScript promises not working on when using with jQuery .change() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-promise

I have followed [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79855/alternate-for-nested-ajax-requests) codereview answer to improve nested jQuery AJAX requests. My app has bunch of `select` tags hierarchy. When use change value in first `select` tag it fires query to `/get_courses/` and it gives a JSON response back. Then I manipulate DOM with that data and create another `select` tag. When user changes value of second `select` tag it will then fire query to `/get_subjects/` and it will also give JSON response back.

So, that is how flow should work.

my HTML code:

```html
<p><select id="university">
    <option value="1">foo</option>
    <option value="2">bar</option>
</select></p>
<p><select id="course_select"></select></p>
<p><select id="subject_select"></select></p>
<p><select id="exams_select"></select></p>
```

I am not able to get the value of `course_select` when using promises. So, I am not able to fire query to `/get_subjects/` and so on.

This is my current js code:

```js
$('#university').change(function() {

    callAjax('http://localhost:8000/exams/get_courses/', {
            'ui': $(this).val()
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            var course_select = document.getElementById('course_select'),
                course_option = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = data[i].id;
                option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].name));
                course_option.appendChild(option);
            }
            course_select.appendChild(course_option);
        })
        .then(
            $('#course_select').change(
                function() {
                    // Here I want to call callAjax method.
                })
        ).then(function(data) {
            // I want to manipulate DOM with data that I got back.
            // But I am not getting value of 'course_select'
        })

});

function callAjax(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: data
    });
}
```

What am I missing here? Or is there any better practices than this?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1u5y7dhn/

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be creating the change event handler inside another change event handler.  Just set them all up at once `$('#university').change(..blah..); $('#course_select').change(..blah..);` etc.

Comment: @DelightedD0D but it is not getting the value of `select` tag.

Comment: @Archer thank you so much. It worked like charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries.  Always KISS :) (not coming on to you :)